# Allow blank value in Date/Time data type

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In the stored procedure I declare values @StartDate, @EndDate and @purchCode

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rp_auto_VIP_RequestInfo]
     @StartDate datetime = null
    ,@EndDate datetime = null
    ,@purchCode nvarchar(50) = null
    ,@TradeSectionId int = 28
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

select 
    @StartDate = CONVERT(date,@StartDate)
    ,@EndDate = CONVERT(date,@EndDate + 1)
```

I want a user to have an option what to choose: either a @purchCode or a @StartDate and an @EndDate. (I use them only as parameters)

@purchCode's data type in ReportBuilder is text so I easily set "Allow blank value".
@StartDate and @EndDate are date/time and I can only choose "Allow null value". However, I don't like the checkbox and want it to be just blank. Can't set data type as text as I still need the calendar.

Tried something (and a lot more) that I found on the Internet:

```
select 
    @StartDate = CASE WHEN @StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(date,@StartDate) ELSE '' END
    ,@EndDate = CASE WHEN @EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(date,@EndDate + 1) ELSE '' END
```

but it says that the dates should be filled

also these:

```
=IIf(Fields!@StartDate.Value = Nothing, Nothing, Fields!@StartDate.Value)

=IIf(Fields!@StartDate.Value <= CDate("1/1/1900"), Nothing, Fields!@StartDate.Value)
```

but it says that I can't get "Value" from parameters

How can I make the dates blank?

Comment: Dates can't be "blank". They *can* be `NULL` though. If you want your user to be able to pass a `NULL` value for the parameter, then tick the "Allow NULL" option in the parameter's settings in SSRS.

Comment: I assume you *aren't* using *both* of the **completely** unsupported versions of SQL Server 2008 and 2012, so I've removed those tags. If the version is important here, then just tag the version you're *actually* using here.

Comment: @ThomA yes, but as I said I don't want the checkboxes to appear. I'm sure there's a way to work around that and still allow the user to not fill the dates

Comment: The alternative would be to use a list of available values which includes `NULL`.

Comment: @ThomA but if I want to choose any date from the calendar, not to choose from the list? Or you meant another thing?

Comment: You can't really do this if you want to us ethe datepicker. How about setting defaults on the dates (to today() for example) and then just ignoring the date parameters in you code if the purchCode parameter is not null/blank.